Google Ad keyword metrics is not matching in Big Query with Google Ads
I have loaded google ads data to Big query using data transfer. I am trying to get keyword and search keyword metrics for my analysis
I used below code from p_ads_KeywordBasicStats table
WITH stats AS (
  SELECT
    campaign_id AS CampaignId,
    ad_group_id AS AdGroupId,
    ad_group_criterion_criterion_id AS CriterionID,
    segments_ad_network_type AS AdNetworkType1,
    metrics_clicks AS Clicks,
    metrics_cost_micros AS Cost,
    segments_date AS Date,
    metrics_impressions AS Impressions
  FROM `micro-reserve.google_ad.p_ads_KeywordBasicStats_xxxxxx
  
),
keywords AS (
  SELECT
    ad_group_criterion_criterion_id AS CriterionId,
    MAX(ad_group_criterion_keyword_text) AS Criteria,
    ad_group_criterion_negative,
    ad_group_criterion_status
  FROM `micro-reserve.google_ad.p_ads_Keyword_xxxxxxx
  
  GROUP BY ad_group_criterion_criterion_id, ad_group_criterion_negative, ad_group_criterion_status
),
campaigns AS (
  SELECT
    campaign_id,
    MAX(campaign_name) AS campaign_name
  FROM `micro-reserve.google_ad.p_ads_Campaign_xxxxx
  
  GROUP BY campaign_id
)
SELECT 
  Clicks,
  Cost,
  Date,
  Impressions,
  Criteria AS Keywords,
  campaign_name,
  ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(Clicks, Impressions) * 100, 2) AS CTR
FROM stats
LEFT JOIN keywords
  ON stats.CriterionID = keywords.CriterionId
LEFT JOIN campaigns
  ON stats.CampaignId = campaigns.campaign_id
WHERE keywords.ad_group_criterion_negative IS FALSE 
  AND keywords.ad_group_criterion_status = 'ENABLED' 
  AND Date BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-13'

==========
Using below query for p_ads_SearchQueryStats table
WITH stats AS (
  SELECT
    campaign_id AS CampaignId,
    ad_group_id AS AdGroupId,
    ad_group_ad_ad_id AS CriterionID,
    segments_ad_network_type AS AdNetworkType1,
    SUM(metrics_clicks) AS Clicks,
    SUM(metrics_cost_micros) AS Cost,
    segments_date AS Date,
    SUM(metrics_impressions) AS Impressions,
    MAX(search_term_view_search_term) AS Criteria,
    search_term_view_status
  FROM `micro-reserve.google_ad.p_ads_SearchQueryStats_xxxxxx
  WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2024-09-13')
  GROUP BY ad_group_ad_ad_id, search_term_view_status, ad_group_id, campaign_id, segments_ad_network_type, segments_date
),
campaigns AS (
  SELECT
    campaign_id,
    MAX(campaign_name) AS campaign_name
  FROM `micro-reserve=.google_ad.p_ads_Campaign_xxxxxxxx
  WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2024-09-13')
  GROUP BY campaign_id
)
SELECT 
  campaigns.campaign_name,
  stats.Date,
  stats.Clicks,
  stats.Impressions,
  stats.Cost,
  stats.Criteria AS Search_Keywords
FROM stats
LEFT JOIN campaigns
  ON stats.CampaignId = campaigns.campaign_id
WHERE stats.Date = '2024-09-13'

The above query works, but the numbers are not matching with Google Ads. Is something I am doing wrong? Can anyone advise please?
